# Magento 2 checkout speed

Tags: magento2, cache, pagespeed

Is it normal if checkout page takes around 17 - 20s to fully load until the loader image disappears and user can enter some data?

I am running magento 2.3-dev branch in production mode, all the cache is on, redis installed on the server. DOM is loaded under 1s, but then there are a lot of html files loaded by ajax and also many minified js. That's why I have to wait around 20 s.

I tried to compare some magento 2 shops and found [this cache extension](http://cache-warmer.m2.mirasvit.com), but even on their shop the checkout page takes around 20s to fully load.

My question is, if this is what I can expect on our live server and if it's normal loading time? Is there something I can do about it?

[image]

Comment: Try timing how long it takes to load with your watch, with the inspector closed. You should find the load time closer to 2-5 seconds. For some reason the inspector makes the load an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. Thank you very much. It takes around 2s. It took me only the whole day to play with this :D

Comment: I ran into the same confusion myself when first looking into it. I had thoughts racing through my head as to "who finds this acceptable for production"??!

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is normal time. In your case, depends from onepage extension. In onepage ext is more forms and files to load.

For normal (not IT) user the most important time is DOM and general load time for give them posibilities start input data to forms.

In one of my config I have +-1s of DOM load, +-2s to General load and +- 9 second to finish. But I use other (https://marketplace.magento.com/espl-onepagecheckout.html) like your (iwd onepage?) extension.

However, if you use in store something like chat or some event tracking like smartlook.com or heapanalytics.com "Finish" time will be longer and little harder to measure.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it as Peter O'Callaghan suggested in the comment to my original question. When I closed the inspector, the overall load time was around 2s which is accurate.